# Laravel: Once Migrating, It doesn't Create Custom Primary Key Column into MySQL

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, artisan-migrate

Here's the problem: I'm trying to generate a very very simple custom `primary key` (by overriding function `getKey()`) for my table `Users`. When I migrate the table, it says:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax Error or Acccess Violation: 1072 Key Column 'uid' Doesn't Exist in Table (SQL: Alter Table 'users' Add Primary Key 'users_uid_primary'('uid'))
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and corrections.

**EDIT**: After migration, my table is created in MySQL but with no primary key column (in this case 'uid').

Schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary('uid');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'uid'; //emphasize that the primary key isn't 'id'
    protected $keyType = 'string'; //p.k. holds string values
    public $incrementing = false; //then p.k. must not auto increment it
    public $timestamps = false; //no need for this one

    public function getKey() {

        return "u".rand(1000, 9999)."r"; //return something like 'u2548r'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually create the field ... you are setting a non existing field `uid` as the primary key.

You need to define the field as some type and add it the table. `Blueprint@primary` is setting an index (in general terms) not creating a field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the field first in your migration:

```
$table->string('uid')->primary();
```

Then set it in your model class

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'uid';

    ...

}
```